# Show that the union of the unit circle and a spiral is not a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

> $M = M_{1} \cup M_{2}$, with $M_{1} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}: x^2 + y^2 =1\}$ and $M_{2}$ is the image of the map $\gamma:(1,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, t \mapsto ((1-\frac{1}{t})\cos(t),(1-\frac{1}{t})\sin(t)).$

Show that $M$ is not a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

We had to show that the Lemniscate of Gerono is not a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in as a previous exercise, which was easy cause it intersected itself. I know the image converges for $t \rightarrow \infty$ to the unit circle. (it looks like a spiral inside the unit circle) But i really don't know how to show that the union of both is not a submanifold. Can someone  give me a hint?

Comment: You want ot show that $M$ is not an **embedded** submanifold. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1791853/intuition-of-immersed-versus-embedded-submanifolds) can be useful. As said in one of the answers the hint is to consider a point in the unit circle and to note how many 'parts' of the spiral intersect a fixed neighborhood of the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Take any point on the circle. Can you find an open set about it that intersects the spiral finite number of times. The point being that can you check that any point on the circle has a neighborhood diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: No, i can't find such an intersection cause no matter how small the neighbourhood of this point on the unit circle is the spiral will intersect it infinitely many times. This would also mean that the intersection of neighbourhood with the set $M$ consists of infinitely many not connected parts - therefore it can't be homeomorpic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So haven't you answered your question ? :)

Comment: @hardy here the operative word should be diffeomorphic. As a manifold is locally diffeomorphic to a euclidean space.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is the differentiability really necessary? In our course we defined it as locally homeomorphic to an euclidean space.

Comment: Of course. A manifold is not merely a topological object and it's definition capures the geometry via the condition of diffeomorphism. Because ultimately you want to do calculus on the manifold.(crude but heuristically accurate)

Comment: Okay, seems legit. I'll talk about this with my professor in the next lecture. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have a book recommendation for you. Look at Guillemin Pollack, just the first 5-6 pages. Great math + great prose. Highly recommended.    Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $M$ is similar to the [closed topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve#Variants), which is also not a manifold, because at some points of $M$, it is not even locally connected, let alone being homeomorphic to the Euclidean space.

Comment: Here you're talking about about the _closed_ topologist's sine curve, I think. (And wouldn't Maud be a _rocktor_ rather than a "rocktorate"?)

Comment: Yes, I should have been clearer about it. (It's just called "rocktorate in rock studies from the Equestrian Institute of Rockology")