# Immersed Submanifold Requirements

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold

Wald's General Relativity textbook reads

> We can use the above definition of integration on manifolds to define the integral of $p-$forms on $M$ over well behaved, orientable $p-$dimensional surfaces in $M.$ First, we must define more precisely the notion of a "well behaved surface." Let $S$ be a manifold of dimension $p<n$. If $\phi: S \to M$ is $C^{\infty}$, is locally one to one - i.e., each $q \in S$ has an open neighborhood $O$ such that $\phi$ restricted to $O$ is one-to-one - and $\phi^{-1}: \phi[O] \to S$ is $C^{\infty}$, then $\phi[S]$ is said to be an *immersed submanifold* of $M.$ If, in addition, $\phi$ is globally one-to-one (i.e., $\phi[S]$ does not "intersect itself"), then $\phi[S]$ is said to be an *embedded submanifold* of $M.$

I am having trouble understanding the necessity of these requirements. What would be an example of a submanifold which is *not* "immersed"? That is, what would a pathological manifold not satisfying the "$\phi: S\to M$ being locally one-to-one" requirement look like?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, the terminology "an immersed submanifold" is suboptimal which leads to questions such as yours. The thing to realize is that an "immersed submanifold" in general is not a *submanifold*!

My preferred terminology is one of an *immersion*, which is a triple
$$
\phi: S\to M
$$
where $\phi$ is a smooth map such that the differential $d\phi_x$ is 1-1 for every $x\in S$. Equivalently, for each $x\in S$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $S$ such that:

a. $\phi(U)$ is a smooth submanifold $N$ in $M$.

and

b. $\phi: U\to  N$ is a diffeomorphism, i.e. a map which has a smooth inverse.

Given this, one can say that a subset $A\subset M$ is an "immersed submanifold" if there exists an immersion $\phi: S\to M$ whose image $\phi(S)$ equals $A$.

To make things worse, Wald's definition of an embedding (an embedded submanifold) is plain wrong! The correct definition is that $\phi$ is an immersion which is a homeomorphism to its image. (This includes, the 1-1 requirement, but  is stronger.)

Examples of immersed submanifolds were discussed many times at MSE, for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1791853/intuition-of-immersed-versus-embedded-submanifolds).

Comment: To his credit, perhaps, immediately thereafter he says in a parenthetical remark "(In some references the additional condition is imposed on embedded submanifolds that $\phi: S \to \phi[S]$ is a homeomorphism with the topology on $\phi[S]$ induced from $M.$)"

Comment: @Jbag1212: "In some references" is the standard definition. It is like saying "some people say that 2x2 equals 4."